# Why sizeToFit also change frame?

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, frame, bounds

Apple document says,

> // calls sizeThatFits: with current view bounds and changes bounds
>   size.

It change view's bounds. But when we call this , like

```
[UILabel sizeToFit]
```

We can find the frame changes according the bounds. I cant understand.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact code you are using?

Comment: I do not understand your question clearly.

Comment: You mean that code also change the position of origin X and Y coordinate?